# Xamarin.Android: Binding aar file not Generation AWS Configured Class

Tags: amazon-s3, xamarin.android

I am Newbie to Xamarin. I am here using my `aar` file for binding it to `xamarin.android`. In a `Service` I have used `TransferListener` but due to that class won't be generated while building xamarin app after removing `Listener`, it is working fine.

Description Edited:
I have created library in android. Now trying to bind generated `aar` file to xamarin. But after building project inside generated `dll` file, I am unable to find a class which has implemented `TransferListener` of `AWS`. When I remove `TransferListener` from there, I found that class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't make sense can you elaborate the situation properly

Comment: @G.hakim Edited in post

Comment: Are you trying to implement amazon aws?

Comment: Yes, I am trying that in android library it is working fine for android but while using aar file of that it is creating problem in xamarin

Comment: There is a xamarin library available for that but if you insist on using the same I would suggest you check if you followed the procedure properly on binding an aar in case you have i would like you to check the debug output while create the aar

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Amazon AWS cloud connection the following are the links that you need to check :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/Welcome.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-mobile-sdk-for-xamarin/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/getting-started-xamarin.html\

https://blog.xamarin.com/amazon-web-services-aws-mobile-sdks-for-xamarin-now-available/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96342/implementing-aws-cognito-identity-services-in-xamarin-android

https://components.xamarin.com/view/aws-cognitoidentity-sdk

Comment: Does Aws mobile sdk content the mobile ads component?

Comment: Yes it should but I'm not 100% sure to be honest